# How to remove y-axis on removing dataset in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to add multiple datasets to the chart, and remove the dataset from chart based on id. I am adding different y-axis for each dataset using yAxisID. When I remove the dataset from chart, y-axis is not being removed. how to remove the corresponding y-axis?

the code is as follows:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 400px;height: 200px;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<button onclick="add_dataset()">add dataset </button>
<button onclick="remove_dataset()">remove random dataset</button>

<script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

    my_chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            datasets: [{
                label: "0",
                yAxisID: "0",
                data: Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)),
                backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
        },
    });

    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }

    function add_dataset(){
        temp = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        let data_store = {
            label: String(my_chart.data.datasets.length),
            yAxisID: String(my_chart.data.datasets.length),
            data: temp,
            backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
        };
        my_chart.data.datasets.push(data_store)
        my_chart.update();
    }

    function remove_dataset(){
        let temp_num =  Math.floor(Math.random() * my_chart.data.datasets.length);

        my_chart.data.datasets.splice(temp_num, 1);

        my_chart.update();
    }
</script>
```

I tried removing the scales from my_chart. but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

in the `options` object, try:

```js
options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        [yAxisId]: {
            display: false,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).